# Have I been hacked?

Tags: etherscan

Why can’t I see the ether in the balance even though the received transactions are there?

```
https://etherscan.io/address/0xdc16771a8461dac99750e806a02f3c5fb298e8de
```

Really confused here, would appreciate another pair of eyes!

Seems like there Are two transfers to an unkown wallet immediately upon receiving the funds, with an insane gas price?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the private key has been compromised and a flash bot is taking the funds from this wallet immediately after they are added.